# How to delay not exist task by celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have two environments
1. webserver
2. celery worker

webserver add jobs to celery message queue. but those env are separated, so can not import task function.

how to call not exist task explicitly?

ex)

```py
# A project (web) - view.py
def view(request): 
    [X] task_a.delay()  
    [O] add_jobs("task_a", *args)
    ...

# B project (worker) - tasks.py
@task
def task_a:
    ...
```

Comment: Please, give us more details. Improve your question.

If you use task.delay(), in your task you have to put a decorator @task, by celery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`send_task` function](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.Celery.send_task) to send a task to a decoupled celery project.

```
from celery.app import Celery
app = Celery(broker_url='the broker url of the celery instance')
app.send_task(name='myapp.mytaskname', kwargs={
  'arg1': 'value1',
  'arg2': 'value2',
})
```